# How to create values from Zipf Distribution with range n in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, distribution

I would like to create an array of Zipf Distributed values withing range of [0, 1000].

I am using [numpy.random.zipf](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.zipf.html) to create the values but I cannot create them within the range I want.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

normalize and multiply by 1000 ?

```
a=2
s = np.random.zipf(a, 1000)
result = (s/float(max(s)))*1000

print min(s), max(s)
print min(result), max(result)
```

althought isn't the whole point of zipf that the range of values is a function of the number of values generated ?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the original answer (Felix) that forcing Zipf values to a specific range is a very unusual thing, and it likely means that you're doing something wrong.

Having said that, I actually had a similar problem, where I really did need to generate Zipf values conforming to a certain criteria. In my case, I wanted to generate a brand new set of data that was similar to an existing data set. I wanted the sum to be the same as the existing distribution, but the values to be different.

My insight is that it's possible to re-generate the values a few times until you get ones you like.

```
#Generate a quantity of Zipf-distributed values close to a desired sum 
def gen_zipf_values(alpha, sum, quantity):
    best = []
    best_sum = 0
    for _ in range(10):
        s = np.random.zipf(alpha,quantity)
        this_sum = s.sum()
        if (this_sum > best_sum) and (this_sum <= sum):
            best = s
            best_sum=this_sum
    return best
```

Again, this solution is tailored to my problem, where I wanted to generate values close to a sum, without going over. I also had a pretty good idea of what I wanted alpha to be in each time. I omitted some of the conditions checking, sorting, etc. for clarity.

If you had to do it more than a few times though (i.e. you had to run the for loop 1 million times to get your distribution), you probably have something wrong (like alpha, or unrealistic expectations on the values). I feel it's valid to 'let the computer do the work', or to hand-pick the best option from a few reasonable ones.